# Should test cases be written for methods that wrap third party code?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd

In my application I have method that validates a CIDR address. All it does is wraps around the `ipv4` `validate_cidr` method:

```
def isValidCIDR(self, cidr):
    return iptools.ipv4.validate_cidr(cidr)
```

I don't like it personally. I'd rather just place the validation check in `main()`.

The only reason I've done it this way is because I write the test to validate a CIDR address:

```
def test_input_for_valid_cidr_format(self):
    cidr = '192.168.2.4/24'
    self.assertTrue(self.scanner.isValidCIDR(cidr))
```

Is there any need to write such a test?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit test wrapper objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414197/unit-test-wrapper-objects)

Comment: A better question is why `isValidCIDR` is an instance method, since `self` is not used in the body. There doesn't seem to be a reason for the wrapper to exist in the first place.

Comment: @chepner it's part of a class, I haven't included any other code or details about the system because there's no purpose in doing so.

Comment: You might consider making it a `@classmethod` then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another answer says:

> The main advantage to having the test is that allows you to switch out
>   the implementation later and be sure that it will still work as
>   expected.

This is the exact reason why I **would** write a test case for wrapped code.  At some point I'm probably going to want to test my code against an updated version of the wrapped code.  If I write a test against it myself, I'll know whether the wrapped code still performs as expected for my use case.

I would also write the test to ensure that I'm not making a bonehead mistake in calling the wrapped code (I make a lot of those).  I.e., getting the arguments in the wrong order:

```
def foo(x, y):
    # Wrapped function.
    ...

def call_foo(x, y):
    # My wrapper
    return foo(y, x)
```

Comment: I'd say a lot of what you are worried about should be handled either by tests in the package itself or by your normal tests, as such I personally don't feel this adds value.

Comment: I agree that this is a matter of preference.  And I've gone the other way too, for exactly the reasons you stated.  As for me, I'm generally just more comfortable writing the test.  It's not a high priority for me, but I do it anyway.

Comment: +1 This technique is explained [here](http://blog.8thlight.com/eric-smith/2011/10/27/thats-not-yours.html) under "Test the wrapper using the third party library directly"

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage to having the test is that allows you to switch out the implementation later and be sure that it will still work as expected.

Personally I would not test a thin wrapper around a library function unless I was doing some logic in the method or was seriously considering switching out the implementation or had concerns about the implementation in certain edge cases. I don't think it offers enough value for the effort put in.